# How to get state value for Amazon cognito?

Tags: salesforce, amazon-cognito

Getting the following error while trying to authenticate using Amazon Cognito in Auth provider salesforce.

> We can’t log you in because of the following error. No_Oauth_State:
> State was not sent back

I am using callback URL as community callback URL.